# Please explain details for Flink on YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

Could anybody explain me the optimal configuration and parallelism for high performance flink jobs on YARN?

I use Cloudera Hadoop with 4 nodes (1 main node + 3 worker nodes) each has 12 CPU and 96 Gb memory.

There are few yarn properties

- yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb - current value is 36Gb
- yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb - current value is 36Gb

I have found out that when I start yarn-session I should set `-tm` flag no more than 36Gb or my application will fail with error `The cluster does not have the requested resources for the TaskManagers available! Maximum Memory: <...> Requested: <...>MB . Please check the 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and the 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb' configuration values` otherwise.

I want to use all of resources available on the cluster to increase performance of my flink jobs. So my questions are:

1. Should I set the above properties almost to 96 Gb (i.e. 88 Gb) and use 1 TaskManager per worker node with 12 slots (3 TaskManagers on 3 nodes, 36 slots total)? Is it common to use huge TaskManagers on YARN?
2. Or should I set `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to 88 Gb and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` to 8 Gb and use multiple TaskManagers per one worker node? For example, 6 TaskManagers per node with 2 slots each (18 TaskManagers on 3 nodes with 36 slots total)? I have read that it is not recommended to set too high value for `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`.
3. Is it enougth to set `-jm` flag to 4 Gb for flink session? Are there any recomendations for this?

Please explain, how does it impact on network traffic, garbage collection, CPU and memory utilization, etc? Which configuration should I use for best performance?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is a very complex task and it is not easy to answer it in SO post. I would recommend to watch this presentation from FlinkForward where you can probably find a few answers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l8dCKMMWkw&t=2055s